# Accessing the types of a tuple_t

Tags: c++, boost, boost-hana

I have this code:

```
auto myTuple = hana::tuple_t<int, char*, long>;
std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id<decltype(myTuple[1_c])>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
```

This outputs:

```
boost::hana::type_impl<char*>::_
```

I want to access the 'char*' type, but if I do:

```
std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id<decltype(myTuple[1_c])::type>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
```

It outputs:

```
error: 'decltype(myTuple[1_c])' (aka 'boost::hana::type_impl<char *>::_ &') is not a class, namespace, or scoped enumeration
std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id<decltype(myTuple[1_c])::type>().pretty_name() << std::endl
```

It's because it is a reference, if I do:

```
std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id<decltype(boost::hana::traits::remove_reference(myTuple[1_c]))::type>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
```

Then it outputs 'char*'.

Is this the way to access the types of a tuple_t? There must be less cumbersome way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed tricky. Hana provides a unary plus operator on `hana::type` that decays any ref-qualified `hana::type` to a rvalue. So basically,

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
namespace hana = boost::hana;
using namespace hana::literals;

auto myTuple = hana::tuple_t<int, char*, long>;
using T = decltype(+myTuple[1_c])::type;
//                 ^~~~~ notice unary plus here
```

Also note that you might be interested in using `hana::experimental::print` from `<boost/hana/experimental/printable.hpp>`. This is an experimental (hence unstable) feature, but I can assure you it should eventually make its way into the library, in one form or the other:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/experimental/printable.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

int main() {
    auto myTuple = hana::tuple_t<int, char*, long>;
    std::cout << hana::experimental::print(myTuple) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
(type<int>, type<char*>, type<long>)
```

**Edit**: The unary plus operator is documented in the [reference of `hana::type`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1type.html).

Comment: "For this reason, types provide an overload of the unary + operator that can be used to turn a lvalue into a rvalue. So when using a result which might be a reference to a type object, one can use + to make sure a rvalue is obtained before fetching its nested ::type". Thanks!