# How to transform a boost::hana::map into lambdas

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-hana

I have the following code

```
template <typename T>
void my_func(T& /*var*/)
{
};

auto my_types = hana::make_map(
  hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<std::uint32_t>, hana::integral_c<std::uint8_t, 1>),
  hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<std::uint16_t>, hana::integral_c<std::uint8_t, 1>)
);

using my_variant = std::variant<std::uint32_t, std::uint16_t>;

auto to_factory = [](auto map)
{
  return hana::transform(map, [](auto pair)
    {
      return [](my_variant& value)
        {
          using T = typename decltype(hana::first(pair))::type;
          T v;
          my_func(v);
          value = v;
        };
    });
};

auto factory = to_factory(my_types);
```

but I always get the error message

```
error: 'boost::hana::type_impl<short unsigned int>::_&' is not a class, struct, or union type
```

when I use `hana::pair` in `my_tuple`. All works fine when I just use

```
auto my_types = hana::make_map(
  hana::type_c<std::uint32_t>,
  hana::type_c<std::uint16_t>
);
```

and obviously no call to `hana::first`

Why do I get back kind of a reference when using `hana::first`?

Comment: [From the documentation of `boost::hana::first`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Product.html#ga34bbf4281de06dc3540441e8b2bd24f4): _"Note that if the `Product` actually stores the elements it contains, `hana::first` is required to return a lvalue reference, a lvalue reference to const or a rvalue reference to the `first` element, where the type of reference must match that of the pair passed to `first`"_

Comment: @dfri sooo what would be the workaround?

Comment: That I do now know, or I would've posted an answer instead of a comment ;)

Comment: found this info [in the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1type.html) _"For this reason, types provide an overload of the unary + operator that can be used to turn a lvalue into a rvalue. So when using a result which might be a reference to a type object, one can use + to make sure a rvalue is obtained before fetching its nested ::type:"_ but its still not working

Comment: So `using T = typename decltype(+hana::first(pair))::type;` did not yield what you expect?

Comment: @dfri got it to work, the container cannot bw `hana::map`, it has to be `hana::tuple`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155645/accessing-the-types-of-a-tuple-t/36157299#36157299

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you are trying to use `hana::map`. `hana::map` is not a `Functor` and has no implementation for `hana::transform`. It is, however `Foldable` so you could use `hana::unpack` and return a new tuple of lambdas if you needed to.

As for `hana::first` along with other accessors including `hana::at`, `hana::at_key`, etc.; They all return reference types so to access members you must strip the reference somehow.

For this you can use the provided `hana::type` unary `+` operator:

```
using type = typename decltype(+hana::first(x))::type;
```

Or you can use `hana::typeid_` which is a bit more readable in my opinion:

```
using type = typename decltype(hana::typeid_(hana::first(x)))::type;
```

I'm not sure if `hana::map` fits with your use case, but here is how you could "transform" it into a tuple of lambdas:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <cstdint>
#include <variant>

namespace hana = boost::hana;


auto my_types = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<std::uint32_t>, hana::integral_c<std::uint8_t, 1>),
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<std::uint16_t>, hana::integral_c<std::uint8_t, 1>)
);

using my_variant = std::variant<std::uint32_t, std::uint16_t>;
auto make_lambda = [](auto pair) {
    return [](my_variant value) {
        using T = typename decltype(hana::typeid_(hana::first(pair)))::type;
        // do stuff
    };
};

auto to_factory = [](auto map) {
    return hana::unpack(map, [](auto ...pairs) {
        return hana::make_tuple(make_lambda(pairs)...);
    });
};

// erm.. you could also do this
auto to_factory_2 = [](auto map) {
    return hana::unpack(map, [](auto ...pairs) {
        return hana::make_tuple(((void)pairs, [](my_variant value) {
            using T = typename decltype(hana::typeid_(hana::first(pairs)))::type;
            // do stuff
        })...);
    });
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/KMdrzS

From your code example, note that you might also run into issues taking a mutable reference to a variant that is being implicitly cast from a different type so I just removed that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have indeed a problem with the variant, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930744/access-stdvariant-inside-lambda) question, any idea how to circumvent it?