# Access std::variant inside lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, variant

I have the following code:

```
std::variant<std::uint32_t, std::uint16_t, float> my_variant;

template <typename T>
void my_sub_func(T& value)
{
  // do stuff
};

void my_func(my_variant& value)
{
  [&]()
  {
    my_sub_func(std::get<std::uint32_t>(value));
  };
};

int main()
{
  my_variant t;
  my_func(t);
}
```

I always get an `Unexpected index` exception at runtime, why is that and how can I avoid it?

Comment: The provided code has other issues, none of which can cause the error; please fix it first.

Comment: unknown `Types`, `my_variant t;` is wrong as `my_variant` is the global variable, not a type.

Comment: Then `std::get<std::uint32_t>(value)` is not called, as your lambda is not called, so cannot have invalid index.

Comment: Once fixed, work as expected [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f51d9855b568f709).